# Socket.io client issues with NGINX deployed socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx, socket.io

**Hi guys**

I have created a simple chat app using an express backend with TypeScript and MongoDB. To send data realtime I have been using [socket.io](http://socket.io). Everything works fine in my [localhost](http://localhost) test-enviroment, but when I deploy my webpage using NGINX it does not.

My own guess is that something is wrong with how I access the socket on the frontend.

Below is my NGINX setup file (site-enabled-defaults), where I set up a specific location for the [socket.io](http://socket.io) and one for my backend REST-endpoints.

I have changed my server name for privacy reasons :)

My NGINX config file: site-enabled-default

```
server {

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                root /var/www/example/;
        }

        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
        location /backend/ {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/segatos.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/segatos.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Here is the setup code server-side of the [socket.io](http://socket.io) part in my app.ts, in this file my entire express server is setup with various options and routes.

```
const app = express();

/*
    More setup code 
    Ratelimit 
    Cors setup
    BodyParser 
*/

const http = require("http");
export const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, { cors: { origin: "*" } });

io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
});
app.set("io", io);

/*
    More express setup with endpoints etc 
/*
```

In the www.ts file I create a database connection and tells the server to listen on my choosen port. Which is defined in a .env file.

```
import { server } from "../app";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3333;

/*
    Some DB connections here 
    Starting the server afterwards 
*/

server.listen(PORT, () =>
    debug(`Server started, listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
  );
```

Frontend wise I am, as before mentioned, using react and have created a SocketProvider component which is using the useContext.

I have then wrapped the child components inside the SocketProvider.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { SERVER_URL_SOCKET } from "../util/Settings";
//SERVER_URL_SOCKET == https://example.com/socket.io/";

const SocketContext = React.createContext();

export function useSocket() {
  return useContext(SocketContext);
}

export function SocketProvider({ id, children }) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(SERVER_URL_SOCKET, { query: { id } });

    setSocket(newSocket);

    return () => newSocket.close();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As it is now, I have tried to change the server url in the SocketProvider to localhost:PORT and tried many different setup configurations for the nginx setup file.

I have also tried to open all ports on the deployed webpage (disabling firewall temporarely).

In the network tab in my browser I can see that [socket.io](http://socket.io) keeps creating this request.

[Picture of network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT2kz.png)

So to summarize my problem is that the backend REST-endpoints are working, but I cannot connect to my socket to use the socket features that work in my local test-enviroment.

For an example when in the local test enviroment  the socket prints "a user connected".

Where lies my misunderstanding in how to setup and use [socket.io](http://socket.io) on a deployed webpage?